# Cutting Power to Solar MPPT

Tags: switches, solar-cell, mppt

I have an EPEver 3210A MPPT connected to my solar panel and a battery to charge. I'm initially experimenting with a small size battery (12V, 7Ah) before I upgrade. The MPPT pulls 100mA from the battery to operate. There is no on/off button on the MPPT.

I don't want to drain the battery too much with the MPPT on inclement days (which happens often during this time of year), so I added a DC switch that kills the connection between the MPPT and the battery. I'm not sure if the manufacturer intended for the MPPT to be under constant use and I'm afraid that using the switch often would put too much stress on the system.

Will a switch that periodically turns the MPPT on and off damage it?

Comment: While it seems unlikely that turning something on and off could be a problem, this is a question that only the manufacturer can answer.  Everything else is just speculation.

Comment: Some charge controllers insist you connect the battery before connecting the solar panel. If yours does, then it might be damaged with the battery disconnected, so don't do that.

Comment: If it really uses 100mA in standby, it is a piece of junk. However, maybe it will transition to a lower power mode after some period of time elapses. So I suggest you do some more measurements to make sure. But if it really uses 100mA in standby, then I suggest that you simply get rid of it.

Comment: @mkeith The accuracy on the MPPT are in increments 0.1 V, so I measured the current draw and it's actually around 35mA. Does that still qualify as a "piece of junk"?

Comment: Maybe not. I mean, it would not be hard to do better. But 0.035A * 12hr = 0.42Ah. That is around 6% of battery capacity lost every night (if the night is 12 hours). Considering that the power loss is less than you expected, do you still even want to use a switch?

Comment: @mkeith Most nights here are longer than 12 hours, so it's preferable. Iyo, what would be a reasonable current draw?

Comment: From a systems design perspective, you want the overnight draw to be much less than what the panels provide in one day, and much less than the battery capacity. From an electronics design perspective, it seems like it would be easy to detect night time and go into a low power state where the average consumption is 5mA or less.

Answer (score 0):

On bigger commercial off grid systems being sold they have a shut down procedure that alows you to turn off/on the system safely. So in your setup if you add breakers or switches in between batteries, charge controllers, panels, inverters and even after inverters you can control your system the way you want safely.